# Objective-C: How can I release this object?

Tags: objective-c

I have a class named "ServerDataLayer" that holds a NSURLConnection, and a NSMutableData that its writing the received HTTP data in to. When the connection finishes, it simply fires a delegate that my caller passed itself as a reference, the method looks like this:

```
-(void) serverDataLayerResponse:(id)entity
{
    if ([entity isMemberOfClass:[LoginResponse class]])
    {
        LoginResponse *response = (LoginResponse*)entity;

        NSLog(@"Error Code: %d", response.errorCode);
        NSLog(@"Error Message: %@", response.errorMessage);
        NSLog(@"Registered: %c", response.registered);
        NSLog(@"AuthToken: %@", response.authToken);

        [AppData shared].authToken = response.authToken;

        ServerDataLayer *request = [[[ServerDataLayer alloc] initWithServer:_serverUrl delegate:self] autorelease];
        [request getPlayerDetails];
        //[_server getPlayerDetails];
    }
}
```

Here's my problem...the internal _receivedData and _connection variables are currently in use whilst this delegate method is in progress. I wanted to use my same ServerDataLayer instance to fire another request off "[_server getPlayerDetails]", but the _connection and _receivedData variables internally were getting overwritten and I was getting in to a mess about when to retain/release at the right time.

So my work around was just to instantiate the ServerDataLayer each time I wanted to talk to the server. Now...in the example above, I'm instantiating the request with an 'alloc', and setting an 'autorelease' as I lose scope of this 2nd request. Will this 2nd request stay in memory whilst it's NSURLConnection is busy internally performing the request?

I'm getting a bit lost at this point on how to manage the object references for this kind of process. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using ARC?

Comment: Yep, I'm using Cocos2d, a 2d game engine, and it doesn't support ARC. Well, it does with a little hacking, but I've not been doing Objective-C for long so not confident enough to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSURLConnection`, if used via the delegate methods will attach itself as an input to a run loop. However it won't retain its delegate. So your `ServerDataLayer` would be deallocated (and hopefully remember to cancel the connection). You could use object associations to give your object the same lifecycle as the URL connection, if you were suitably careful about the potential retain loop.

If you use `sendAsynchronousRequest:...` then you'll probably be fine anyway; assuming you reference `self` or any instance variable in the completion block then you'll be retained by the block and live for at least as long as it does.

There's really no need to confuse yourself over retain/release any more. Even if ARC isn't an option, you can just declare the relevant instance variables as retain properties within a class extension and use self.property notation to set new values. Retains and releases will be handled for you.

The only caveat is that you should never use dot notation in either your `init` or `dealloc` as a special case of the rule that it isn't safe to call methods on a class that's only half instantiated or is half destroyed.

Comment: That's great advice, thanks Tommy. If I can't use dot notation in an init function, then how would I set class variables from passed in params?

Comment: @MeshMan there'll be an instance variable backing the `@property` though its name will depend on exactly how you @synthesize and if you do at all (it's no longer required). If you specify something explicit it'll be that. If you just `@synthesize` it'll be the same name as the property. If you leave the `@synthesize` implicit it'll be the property name with an underscore at the start (aside: sadly Apple appear to have flipflopped on instance variable naming, making this slightly more complicated than it needs to be)

Answer (score 1):

Just use multiple `ServerDataLayer` instances.

Comment: Will the runtime now destroy the instance in that example though when the function finishes, since the autorelease will call release on it, and no one has retained it? It appears as though its working fine, but I'm not sure how it is working. I'm assuming the runtime knows the NSURLConnection thread is working with the object?

Comment: @MeshMan "*…I'm not sure how it is working"* if you want to understand how this all fits together (and I encourage its importance), I suggest you load up Instruments->Leaks, then run your program and evaluate the reference count operations of the objects in question. either that, or write some programs without ARC (for a better understanding of these relationships and objects', run loops', and autorelease pools' reference operations). understanding can't be reduced to a comment box.